# How to use "Update Contact" to run Opt-out during a Journey for a following up email

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

This Journey contains two emails: 1st email and 2nd email is sent 7 days later to the non-clickers of the 1st email. I need to run opt-out before sending the 2nd email.

I have added "Update Contact" in the journey before the 2nd email. I can manually run a Opt-out suppression query in the DE before the 7th day to update the Opt-in list but does the "Update Contact" get updated; i.e., it will update the opt-in?

What is the best practice to update Suppression for opt-out during a journey?

Comment: Hi Carol. Was my answer helpful to you?

Answer (score 0):

The best approach will be to introduce the exit criteria to the journey. It will evaluate each time a contact leaves a wait-step.

You don't need to use the Update Contact activity to achieve what you want.

Let's assume you have a *Master* data extension, which holds all your subscribers. And let's assume one of the fields in the DE is a boolean field, describing whether or not your contact has opted in to receiving emails.

If this DE is connected to your data model in Data Designer, you can refer to it in your exit criteria, and define everyone who has the boolean field set to *false*, should exit the journey:

[image]